# Workaround for adding localization to new file in Beta Xcode 6.3

Tags: xcode, localization, beta

does anyone know of a work around for this issue?
When trying to localize the 'Localizable.strings' file after choosing for which language the file should be set, nothing happens :(.
I tried it a few times with no success.

But when I close my project, reopen it in Xcode 6.2 and do the same action in there... Xcode adds the localization for the selected languages without any problem.

I know it is a bug for the Beta release of Xcode, but I would appreciate a working workaround for this.

thx

Comment: Xcode 6.3 shipped, is this still an issue?

Comment: Seems fixed in 6.3 Michael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be fixed in version 6.3 of Xcode